# How to use fluentd+elasticsearch+grafana to display the first 12 characters of the container ID?

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

Need to use fluentd to collect logs of kubernets and store logs in elasticsearch. And use grafana to display logs and digests. However, the docker's container id is 64 characters. How to set the fluentd, or elasticsearch, or grafana, to display just first 12-character of container id in grafana?

my config file as follow:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/fluentd-es-configmap.yaml

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this at the end of **containers.input.conf**:

```
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    docker.container_id ${record["docker.container_id"][0,12]}
  </record>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay to only store 12-character IDs, you can add a fluent filter parser (tested with Fluent Bit only):

parsers.conf

```
[PARSER]
   Name    dockerid_parser
   Format  regex
   Regex   ^(?<container_id>.{12})
```

fluent-docker.conf

```
[SERVICE]
    ...
    Parsers_File /full/path/to/parsers.conf
...
[FILTER]
    Name         parser
    Match        *
    Key_Name     container_id
    Parser       dockerid_parser
    Reserve_Data On
...
```